# What is the difference between experiment and experimentation?

Tags: meaning

If I am correct, both *experiment* and *experimentation* exist in English. Which one should I use? Can I say the following two sentences?

- This week, I am conducting new experiments at the laboratory
- This week, I am conducting new experimentations at the laboratory

If the answer is yes, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Experimentation is the act of doing experiments.

So you would say "I am conducting new experiments at the laboratory"

eg. "not all experimentation is done in a laboratory" means sometimes experiments are done outside the lab.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a difference.

Experiment is a test

Experimentation is the **act** of carrying out a test, or doing tests.

E.g.:

> Over 200 experiments are carried out each week at the laboratory.
>   The new car is undergoing experimentation by the expert drivers at the race track.

Answer (score 2):

*experimentation*

The act, process, or practice of experimenting.

Usage:

- Children need the opportunity for experimentation.
- Extensive experimentation is needed before new drugs can be sold.
- Experimentation with illegal drugs is dangerous.

*experiments*

A test under controlled conditions that is made to demonstrate a known truth, examine the validity of a hypothesis, or determine the efficacy of something previously untried.

Usage:

- Some people believe that experiments on animals should be banned.
- Scientists are conducting/carrying out/doing
  experiments to test the effectiveness of the new drug.
- I've bought a different kind of coffee this week as an experiment (=
  in order to see what it is like).
- We can only find the best solution by experiment.

Comment: I think this answer might be slightly confusing. For your example sentences for "experiment", the first and fourth would read fine with "experimentation" (singular), but not the second or third.